# NGXS updating state using operators and then persisting data to firebase

Tags: angular, ngxs

I've got a action type class to update a user:

```js
export class Update {
    public static readonly type = '[Users] Update';
    constructor(public readonly id: string, public readonly changes: Partial<User>) {}
}
```

And the following is action:

```js
@Action(Update)
public update({ getState, setState }: StateContext<UsersStateModel>, { id, changes }: Update) {
    setState(
        patch({
            users: updateItem(u => u.id === id, patch(changes))
        })
    );

    // const userToUpdate = getState().users.find(u => u.id === id);

    // return this.userService.update(userToUpdate);
}
```

However I can't wrap my head around how to properly send this data to my http service. All other examples I've found include sending data first to the backend and only then assigning result to state.

The code that is commented does the job, but does not *feel right*. Any suggestions how to make this work properly?

Comment: If it was NGRX i would use effects for that. But it seems everything handled in actions in NGSX. May be you can split your actions into sth like updateRequested, updateCompleted. In updateRequested you just make a call to your api and once result returns you dispatch updateCompleted and you patch your state in there.

Comment: What doesn't feel right for me is, that you are trying to send an object from the state to your backend. That mean you are possibly reflecting wrong data to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this maybe?

```
@Action(Update)
public update({ getState, setState }: StateContext<UsersStateModel>, { id, changes }: Update) {
  const currentUser = getState().users.find(u => u.id === id);
  const userWithAppliedChanges = { ...currentUser, ...changes };
  return this.userService.update(userWithAppliedChanges).pipe(
    map(updatedUser => setState(...)),
    catchError(() => EMPTY)
  );
}
```

Comment: This should certainly work, haven't really thought about it, thank you. Also, could you elaborate more on your comment? I understand there's something concerning you in this approach. How would you handle that differently? I'm open to suggestions :)

Comment: I mean that you changed your state before you know that the server request worked. That's called optimistic. What happens when the server request failed for any reason? My suggestion is my answer above.

Comment: Gotcha! I didn't realize you were speaking about optimistic updates. I haven't thought too much about it since it's a learning app, but quick thought is that I could undo the update and return an error, I do know what is the user I was going to update, right? :) In any case - thank you! This was helpful.